# How can I kill a zombie process whose parent is PID = 0?

Tags: macos, zombie-process

Often, when running LLDB on OSX, the debugger will sporadically crash (this just seems to be the nature of LLDB). When this happens, I get a zombie process (the one I was debugging) that looks really strange. It has parent PID = 0:

My process is called: worker

Here is the output of `ps aux | grep worker`

```
root            22785   0.0  0.0        0      0   ??  Z     3:48pm   0:00.00 (worker)
```

As you can see, the process has a PID, but it has no parent PID. This does nothing

```
sudo kill -9 <pid>
```

In fact, nothing short of a restart seems to get rid of it. How can I kill a process like that? I need the process to die, because it holds on to ports that I need.

Answer (score 1):

*Zombie* is the name given to processes which already died. So they do **not run any longer** and they **do not consume system resources** any longer. They are only listed in the process table which could not be properly updated at the time the *zombie* process finished running. This is also the reason why they are not assigned to any meaningful parent.
Therefore you can not kill a *zombie* for a second time (as their name already implies, in contrary to what happens in medium-level horror movies :-)). In most operating systems it is enough to wait for some time for the *zombie* processes to disappear from the list of processes. Or you have to do a reboot if you can not live with this.
Rest assured, *zombies* will do no harm to you.

Comment: Why the excessive formatting of 'zombie' in *italics* or as `code`? It's a normal word.

Comment: @cybermonkey To improve readability? I am not aware that using code formatting for other goals is harmful in any case... but to please you I have changed formatting :-)

Comment: It actually *impairs* readability rather than actively improves it. I myself did that once and was [targeted over on Meta for it](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308047/is-using-backticks-for-inline-quotes-acceptable/308052#308052).

Comment: Zombies DO harm me. This zombie holds a port open on my machine that prevents me from starting another copy of the process. So no, this is not just some "soon to die" process - it is very much alive and kicking

Comment: @Thomas Kejser This is not the zombie that kicks you. This is the kernel TCP network connection table that does. Properly closed TCP network connections disappear from it. If one party just dies such connection can not get a RST which would end it. The TCP/IP standard does not mandate how long to wait to clear such connections (theoretically: forever - the kernel does not know why no party is sending data; its **perfectly ok not to send data** over an open connection). Most TCP/IP stack implementations clear such connections in 24 hrs.

Comment: @Thomas Kejser Look for your process ID in the output of ` netstat -p | fgrep <pid>` if you can see the connection listed (and what state it is in)

Comment: @ArturOpalinski That's all fine - but it has no practical use to hang around and wait for the timeout (I need to be in control of my box). But not being able to kill a process is a major design flaw in the entire Linux/FreeBSD/OSX kernel. I am assuming that the parent PID of 0 means that the kernel has adapted the process - is it possible to have the kernel signal and wait for it on my behalf

Comment: *not being able to kill a process is a major design flaw in the entire Linux/FreeBSD/OSX kernel* - The design flaw is in the debugger that is crashing, not the kernel itself.

Comment: @TheDarkKnight So you are claiming that a properly written kernel should not be in control of the processes it manages? Irrespective of how dumb they behave?

Comment: @ThomasKejser, no I've not made any such claim. As I understand it, you've stated the debugger crashes, but the target application at the time of the crash holds a resource in the form of a network port. Since the port was not cleanly released by the target application, the kernel doesn't know that it should be released. This design is correct and it's the debugger crashing that is the issue here, not how the kernel handles process state.

Comment: @TheDarkKnight OK, so let me understand correctly: Are you claiming that is should not be possible - as root - to forcefully terminate this zombie? Or do you agree that there should be a way to end this process after it has been orphaned?

Answer (score 1):

The situation is that it is not possible, as a user, to clean up a zombie process; the kernel will handle it when it's ready, if possible.

As detailed in [Mac OS X and iOS Internals](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1118057651),

> it is a perfectly normal state and every process usually spends an infinitesimal amount of time, just before it can rest in peace....Parents who outlive, yet forsake their children and move on to other things, will damn the children to be stuck in the quasi-dead state of a zombie. Zombies are, for all intents and purposes, quite dead.

Since the debugger acts as the parent to its target process, which holds a network port and the debugger has crashed, it leaves the target process in the zombie state. The problem here is the crash of the debugger.

Comment: OK, so no way to force the kernel to clean up immediately? That is just terrible OS design

Answer (score 1):

What needs to be done is attach to the running parent. Init should clean up these processes for you.

We can create a defunct process the following way:

```
bash$ (sleep 1 & exec /bin/sleep 5000) &
```

Now we can check for our defunct process:

```
$ ps -C sleep
PID TTY          TIME CMD
22582 pts/3    00:00:00 sleep
22583 pts/3    00:00:00 sleep <defunct>
```

So we have to get the parent ID of the child. In this case, it's easy, but if you don't know the parent we can just use `ps -o ppid= 22583`

So once you have this information, you can attach to the parent and `call waitpid()`

```
$ gdb
(gdb) attach 22582
(gdb) call waitpid(22583,0,0)
$1=22583
(gdb) detach
(gdb) quit
```

And we can see that the defunct process is cleaned with another `ps -C sleep`:

```
 PID TTY          TIME CMD
22582 pts/3    00:00:00 sleep
```

I hope this helps.

edit: Zombies do not take up resources. They *DO* however take up a slot in the kernel's process table, if there's no more space there, then it may be impossible to start another process.